# How many seconds between now and a specific time in C

Tags: c, time, count

I need to be able to count the seconds between now and a specific time (like the next time it's 3pm). I saw some similar questions but I wasn't able to use any of these.

Comment: Well, it's best if you convert that 'specific time' to the Unix timestamp and use the C standard library `time` function to obtain the current timestamp - see here: http://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Comment: What exactly is obscure to you in the time-counting related questions? It would be better if you ask about a specific problem/difficulties you encountered :)

Comment: How is the "specific time" specified? Is it just an English phrase like "the next time it's 3pm"? It seems to me that specifying the time is the biggest part of the problem; once you've done that, determining the difference (hint: `difftime()`) between now (hint: `time(NULL)`) and the specified time is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

C standard library has two representation of time: `time_t` is a seconds since [Unix Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and `struct tm` where you can individially set seconds, minutes, etc.

So to get next moment in time when wall clock will show `3 p.m.` you'll need take current time in seconds `time(NULL)`, convert it to `struct tm`, advance time to 3 p.m. by setting structure fields, convert it back to `time_t` and calculate the difference:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    time_t now, next3pm;
    struct tm threepm;

    // Get current time (now)
    now = time(NULL);

    // Copy current date to a `threepm`, and set time
    memcpy(&threepm, gmtime(&now), sizeof(struct tm));
    if(threepm.tm_hour > 15) {
        // Advance to a next day
        ++threepm.tm_mday;
    }

    threepm.tm_hour = 15;
    threepm.tm_min = threepm.tm_sec = 0;

    printf("%.f seconds till 3:00 PM\n", difftime(mktime(&threepm), now));

    return 0;
}
```

I used UTC conversion functions `gmtime()`/`mktime()`. Since there is no timezoned version of `mktime()` you may need to convert time on your own. Using UTC time may cause trouble with advancing to a next day when it shouldn't do that (because it is already 15:00 according to UTC, but not yet 15:00 according to a local time).

---

Or, a [classic joke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5npF.jpg) version:

```
int main() {
    time_t t;
    struct tm* tm;
    do {
        t = time(NULL);
        tm = gmtime(&t);
        usleep(1000000);
    } while(tm->tm_hour != 15 && tm->tm_min != 0);

    puts("0 seconds till 3:00 PM");
}
```